# Prevent close during BeforeSave event

Tags: excel, vba

### Question:

A user attempts to close a file they've made changes to. A prompt comes up asking if they would like to save and they click 'Yes'. If there is code in the BeforeSave event that cancels the save, is there a way to also cancel the closing?

### Background:

We make frequent use of "blank files", pre-formatted files with formulas and such that a user can open, enter data, and save under a new file name. It's that last step that caused problems. Users would save their data to the blank file, which meant we'd have to restore it to its original condition (clear out data, re-enter formulas that were deleted/overwritten, revert changes to formatting, etc.).

To prevent this, I added the following code to all blank files:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    If instr(UCase$(ThisWorkbook.Name), "BLANK") <> 0 then
        If SaveAsUI = False Then
            MsgBox "This is the blank file. You can't save it. " _
              & "Please choose 'Save As' and save with a new file name.", _
              vbExclamation, "Can't Save Blank"
            Cancel = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

If the user tries to save data to a blank file, they'll get a message telling them they can't, and to use the Save As dialog instead. And if I need to make changes to the blank file, I can use the Save As dialog to save it using the same file name.

The problem lies when I make changes to a blank file and try to close that file. The prompt will come up asking me if I want to save my changes. Not thinking about it, I'll click 'Yes'. Then my code will be triggered preventing a save and notifying me, as intended. But when I click 'OK' on my message, the file immediately closes without saving changes.

What I'd like is some way to prevent the file from closing when saving has been canceled.

Comment: Why aren't you using a template workbook like BLANK,xlst that won't get overwritten. Opening a new workbook based on a template will create a new standard workbook, e.g. BLANK1.xlsx like the regular Book1.xlsx.

Comment: ...or mark your blank files as "read only" in Explorer (right-click >> Properties >> Read-only)

Comment: To be honest, I didn't know about template workbooks. I'll look into that. Marking the file as Read Only could work, but I think my solution makes things a little more clear for the end user. And my solution works just fine, save this one issue. But the question still stands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the code from there and modified it.

[save as dialog excel code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29522278/save-as-dialog-excel-code)

I hope it solves your problem or at least it will after some small changes.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim varResult As Variant
    Dim ActBook As Workbook

    'displays the save file dialog
    varResult = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:= _
             "Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx", Title:="Save As", _
            InitialFileName:=Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path)

    'checks to make sure the user hasn't canceled the dialog
    If varResult <> False Then
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=varResult '_
        'FileFormat:=xlWorkbookNormal
        Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub


' No it is just in case the user doesn't want to save the file and cancels the first dialog

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    If InStr(UCase$(ThisWorkbook.Name), "BLANK") <> 0 Then
        If SaveAsUI = False Then
            MsgBox "This is the blank file. You can't save it. " _
              & "Please choose 'Save As' and save with a new file name.", _
              vbExclamation, "Can't Save Blank"
            Cancel = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

---

Edit:

After pressing closing button:

- Everytime changes have been made a window to 'save as' pops up and after saving a copy it just closes, no more poping up windows afterwards
- If no changes have been made it just closes the workbook

the code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim varResult As Variant
    Dim ActBook As Workbook

    If InStr(UCase$(ThisWorkbook.Name), "BLANK") <> 0 Then
        If Not ThisWorkbook.Saved Then

            'displays the save file dialog
            varResult = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:= _
                     "Excel Files (*.xlsm), *.xlsm", Title:="Save As", _
                    InitialFileName:=Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path)

            'checks to make sure the user hasn't canceled the dialog
            If varResult <> False Then
                ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=varResult '_
                'FileFormat:=xlWorkbookNormal
                ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
                Exit Sub
            Else
                ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
            End If

        End If
    End If

End Sub


' Just in case the user presses save in options

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    If InStr(UCase$(ThisWorkbook.Name), "BLANK") <> 0 Then
        If SaveAsUI = False Then
            MsgBox "This is the blank file. You can't save it. " _
              & "Please choose 'Save As' and save with a new file name.", _
              vbExclamation, "Can't Save Blank"
            Cancel = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

---

Final version

After pressing closing button:

- Everytime changes have been made a window asking if you want to save changes appears (one can cancel it, say no or yes)
- If yes was chosen (default button) a 'save as' window pops up and after saving a copy it just closes, no more poping up windows afterwards
- If no changes have been made it just closes the workbook

The code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim varResult As Variant
    Dim ActBook As Workbook
    Dim MsgBoxAnswer As Variant

    If InStr(UCase$(ThisWorkbook.Name), "BLANK") <> 0 Then
        If Not ThisWorkbook.Saved Then

            MsgBoxAnswer = MsgBox("Do you want to save changes?", vbYesNoCancel + vbExclamation + vbDefaultButton1, "Microsoft Office Excel")

            If MsgBoxAnswer = vbYes Then


                MsgBox "This is the blank file. Save it with a new file name.", _
                vbExclamation, "Can't Save Blank"

                'displays the save file dialog
                varResult = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:= _
                         "Excel Files (*.xlsm), *.xlsm", Title:="Save As", _
                        InitialFileName:=Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path)

                'checks to make sure the user hasn't canceled the dialog
                If varResult <> False Then
                    ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=varResult '_
                    'FileFormat:=xlWorkbookNormal
                    ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
                    Exit Sub
                Else
                    ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
                End If

            ElseIf MsgBoxAnswer = vbNo Then

                ThisWorkbook.Saved = True

            ElseIf MsgBoxAnswer = vbCancel Then

                Cancel = True

            End If

        End If
    End If

End Sub


' Just in case the user presses save in options

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    If InStr(UCase$(ThisWorkbook.Name), "BLANK") <> 0 Then
        If SaveAsUI = False Then
            MsgBox "This is the blank file. You can't save it. " _
              & "Please choose 'Save As' and save with a new file name.", _
              vbExclamation, "Can't Save Blank"
            Cancel = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This causes the 'Save As' dialog to pop up every time I try to close the file, even if no changes to the file have been made. If changes have been made, but I don't want to save them, I click cancel at the 'Save As' dialog and I'll immediately get the "Do you want to save the changes you've made to 'EXAMPLE.xls'?" dialog. I'll look into it a little further, but it doesn't look like this will do the job.

Comment: I have improved it, it wasn't that hard. I just used a Workbook.Saved property. I hope now it does the job. If you don't like that it pops up straightaway a "Save As" window when changes are made, you can add some other window (that shouldn't be hard), I mean something imitating that 'do you want to save changes' window.

Comment: I added the 'do you want to save changes' window before save as. Look at the 'final edit'.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay, two very high priority projects were dropped on me at the same time.

Your edits were more or less what I had at my last comment, but it just didn't occur to me to set the Workbook.Saved property.

I'm not sure that I'll end up using this method, but it does satisfactorily answer the question.