# Excel isn't able to open a file after saved with VBA Macros

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I've just encountered an unspecific issue during my Excel VBA development:
When the file is saved via macro, it cannot be opened afterwards.

Navigating and saving is okay within the file when it is still opened after the saving procedure, but when it is closed and re-opened, the following error message is displayed:
"Sorry, we couldn't find C:\test.xlsx. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?"

**Edit:** The file is created in the related directory and can be selected within the Windows Explorer

The file cannot be opened anymore after this point.

Please find the used saving procedure below (code copied from two sources as indicated).

The code is executed after clicking a button added to the Worksheet:

```
Sub btnSaveMacro()
    Helper.saveDialog
End Sub
```

It redirects to a save dialog procedure I've copied from [How to save a file selected in Save As dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29522278/how-to-save-a-file-selected-in-save-as-dialog)

```
' Source - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29522278/how-to-save-a-file-selected-in-save-as-dialog
Sub saveDialog()
    'MsgBox ("Save")
    Dim varResult As Variant
    Dim ActBook As Workbook

    'displays the save file dialog
    varResult = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:= _
             "Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx", Title:="Save Report As", _
            InitialFileName:="C:\")

    'checks to make sure the user hasn't canceled the dialog
    If varResult <> False Then
        deleteAllButtons
        deleteAllVBACode
        ActiveWorkbook.saveAs Filename:=varResult, _
        FileFormat:=xlWorkbookNormal
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

This calls the simple subroutine

```
Sub deleteAllButtons()
    ActiveSheet.Buttons.Delete
End Sub
```

and another Sub I've copied from http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx

```
' Source - http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx    
Sub deleteAllVBACode()
    Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
    Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
    Dim CodeMod As VBIDE.CodeModule

    Set VBProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject

    For Each VBComp In VBProj.VBComponents
        If VBComp.Type = vbext_ct_Document Then
            Set CodeMod = VBComp.CodeModule
            With CodeMod
                .DeleteLines 1, .CountOfLines
            End With
        Else
            VBProj.VBComponents.Remove VBComp
        End If
    Next VBComp
End Sub
```

When the Sub saveDialog() ends, I'm able to navigate and save the created Workbook without problems, but cannot re-open the file due to above Excel error message.

I've debugged the code several times, but wasn't able to find the cause.

I would be happy to receive some help as I'm not very familiar with saving routines in VBA.

Comment: `FileFormat:=xlWorkbookNormal` saves a file as an `.xls` file. You need to change  to `FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook`

Comment: Thank you very much! This indeed solved the error message.