# Save As option in the Active workbook path

Tags: excel, vba

Good Morning,

I would like to have the "Save As" directory in the same path, where my initial workbook comes from.
My situation looks like this:
[image]

I have my default file in the directory CF10. After the SaveAs option my new file is saved in the Documents. I don't want that. I want to my SaveAs window popped-up in the same path, from where my initial file comes from.

In my code I set the `path =` , but I think, that is somewhat too late, as File starts to treat the newly saved workbook as the `Active` or `This` one.
I need some solution, which will set the path just before the new workbook is saved.

Is that possible?

```
 Sub SaveAs()
 Dim name As String, name2 As String, custom_name As String, filename As String

 Dim fs As Worksheet

 Dim fPth As Object
 Set fPth = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
 Set fw = Sheets("Frontsheet")
 'name = fw.Range("AA9")
  name = fw.Range("D18")
 name2 = fw.Range("D38")
 custom_name = "DPP_" & name & "_v." & name2 & ".0"
  path = ActiveWorkbook.path & "\" & custom_name

 'Statement for As-built version

 If fw.Range("D38").Value = "As-built" Then
 custom_name = "DPP_" & name & "_AS-BUILT"
 End If

 Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=custom_name, FileFormat:=52

filename = custom_name

 With fPth
.InitialFileName = filename
.Title = "Save your File"
.FilterIndex = 2
.InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList
If .Show <> 0 Then
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=.SelectedItems(1), FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
 End If
 End With

 End Sub
 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EP3u0.png
```

Comment: Check out this post, it may help:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29522278/how-to-save-a-file-selected-in-save-as-dialog

Answer (score 0):

The solution can look like this:

```
 Sub SaveAs()
 Dim name As String, name2 As String, custom_name As String, filename As String

 Dim fs As Worksheet

'Dim fPth As Object
'Set fPth = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
 Set fw = Sheets("Frontsheet")
'name = fw.Range("AA9")
 name = fw.Range("D18")
 name2 = fw.Range("D38")
 custom_name = "DPP_" & name & "_v." & name2 & ".0"


 'Statement for As-built version

 If fw.Range("D38").Value = "As-built" Then
 custom_name = "DPP_" & name & "_AS-BUILT"
 End If

 path = ActiveWorkbook.path & "\" & custom_name & ".xlsm"

   'Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=path, FileFormat:=52

filename = custom_name

  'With fPth
    '.InitialFileName = filename
    '.Title = "Save your File"
    '.FilterIndex = 2
    '.InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList
  'If .Show <> 0 Then
  ' ThisWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=.SelectedItems(1), 
  FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
  'End If
  'End With

 End Sub
```

Where in the line `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs` we can put `filename=path` then everything comes alright. We must remember the file extension.

Moreover, I switched off the Popup file dialog lines. Now the file can be saved directly not through Save As option.

Comment: Please move your ```path = ActiveWorkbook.path & "\" & custom_name & ".xlsm"``` to BELOW the IF statement block, or the IF statement won't work.