# Getting Save As Form with using SaveFileDialog without using a button in Visual Basic

Tags: vba, savefiledialog

In one function in class, I am writing some things in a excel. When this finish, I need to save as form and I want to file name from user. But I dont want to do a form and get button. I want to  when code runs, Excel writing is finished, after that I want to get save as form and get file name and save to the desktop. I saw many examples about SaveFileDialog with button click but I can not find a example that I want. How can I do that ?

```
Dim SaveFileDialog1 As SaveFileDialog
Dim RichTextBox1 As RichTextBox
SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel Files|*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm"

If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            
      My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(SaveFileDialog1.FileName, RichTextBox1.Text, True)
End If
```

Comment: Take the code from the example you saw and paste it in your code after `Excel writing is finished`? There's nothing special about the code just because it's launched from a button click.

Comment: I edited my code. So you can check it. There is no trigger button or something to work  these lines. I am getting an error. above first code, there is nothing about SaveFileDialog. Excel file is written and I want to save it with Save As form

Comment: Are you using VBA or VB.NET?

Comment: I am using VBA sir

Comment: That code is for VB. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29522278/how-to-save-a-file-selected-in-save-as-dialog) and adapt to your usage